# Passing variables from html to javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, geocoding

I'm trying to geocode a user submitted address and store it into a database. The form calls a php file where javascript retrieves the address and geocodes it. Then the lat and lng values are passed to php and stored in a database, however the only values in the database are zeros.

The HTML file:

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <form action="registerEvent.php" id="form" method="post">       
        <input id="address" name="address" placeholder="Adrese" type="text">                    
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>             
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

registerEvent.php:

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<script>
var geocoder;
var inputLat;
var inputLng;

function codeAddress() {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

    var inputLat = event.latLng.lat(); 
    var inputLng = event.latLng.lng();    

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });

}

function passvariable() { 
  window.location.href = "registerEvent.php?lat=" + inputLat;
  window.location.href = "registerEvent.php?lng=" + inputLng; 
}

    codeAddress();
    passvariable();

</script>



<?php
    require("dbinfo.php");

    $connection=mysqli_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

    $lat =$_GET['inputLat']; 
    $lng =$_GET['inputLng']; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO sometable (lat, lng)
VALUES ('$lat', '$lng')";

    if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
    };

    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `window.location.href` twice and the variables seem incorrect in the PHP part (`$_GET['inputLat']` instead of `lat`, and `$_GET['inputLong']` instead of `lon`)

If the HTML file is a separate file, then you need to get the address in a different way:
replace

```
var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
```

with

```
var address = "<?php echo $_POST['address']; ?>"
```

The JS functions should look more like this

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jsv=3.exp&signed_in=true">
</script>
<script> 
var geocoder;
var inputLat;
var inputLng; 

function codeAddress() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var inputLat = event.latLng.lat(); 
    var inputLng = event.latLng.lng();    
    window.location.href = "registerEvent.php?lat=" + inputLat + "&lng=" + inputLng;
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });

}
codeAddress();
</script>
```

And the PHP part:

```
    // ...
    $lat =$_GET['lat']; 
    $lng =$_GET['lng']; 

    if (!empty($lat) && !empty($lng)) {    
       $sql = "INSERT INTO sometable (lat, lng) VALUES ('$lat', '$lng')";
       if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql)) {
         die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
       };
    }

    mysqli_close($connection);
```

If everything is in the same file, the form button should be changed to something like this:

```
<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="codeAddress()">Send</button>
```

Comment: I think the HTML file is a separate file and registerEvent.php displays the javascript that redirects to itself, and it then saves

Answer (score 0):

In your code the form do a `POST` to the PHP page but you post only the address field without getting any coord from google api.

Plus the API you are calling gives a complex return type, you should inspect it... to get lat and lng you have to choose one element from array and check what's in `geometry.location`... (You may check: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderResult)

So, first, do an ajax call to get coords before posting the form.

Just add `onsubmit="return codeAddress();"` then add in your codeAddress function a `return false;` to prevent default action (prevent submit of form itself) and send data to registerEvent.php by GET with a function like this.

In your HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function codeAddress() {
           var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
           var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
           geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               var inputLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(); 
               var inputLng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();    
               window.location.href = "registerEvent.php?inputLat=" + inputLat + "&inputLng=" + inputLng;
             } else {
               alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
             }
           });
           return false;
        }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="registerEvent.php" id="form" method="post" onsubmit="return codeAddress()">       
       <input id="address" name="address" placeholder="Adrese" type="text">                    
       <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>             
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

In your PHP:

```
<?php
require("dbinfo.php");
$connection=mysqli_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}
$lat =$_GET['inputLat']; 
$lng =$_GET['inputLng']; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO sometable (lat, lng) VALUES ('$lat', '$lng')";
if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
};
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Once, a used this snippet to get lat/lng from an address, all in PHP (old API):

```
$address = "......";
$json = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=".urlencode($address));
$json = json_decode($json);

if ($json->status == "OK")
    return $json->results[0]->geometry->location;
```

Answer (score -1):

the javascript is looking for a value

```
var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
```

in the html input and there is no value:

```
<input id="address" name="address" placeholder="Adrese" type="text">
```